# How to fill this iframe src with the value of this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `div` tag on my page:

```
<div class="widget-content">https://www.somelink.com</div>
```

And also this `iframe` tag:

```
<iframe frameborder='0' height='100%' src='' width='100%'/>
```

Is it possible to fill `iframe` `src` with the "https://www.somelink.com" value from `.widget-content`?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? Why do you want to achieve?

Comment: I tried with .attr("src").replace() but I still don't how to get the value from .widget-content

Comment: The `div` doesn't have a value. Do you mean the text content?

Comment: Exactly, preferably only links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This standalone web page, containing HTML, CSS and JS will do what you asked. In this case, we get Kodak's main page (only because they don't prevent framing their site--many others do).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #myIframe {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="widget-content">https://www.kodak.com</div>

        <iframe id="myIframe" frameborder='0' height='100%' src='' width='100%'/></iframe>

        <script>
            var doc = document
                , myNewPage = doc.querySelector( 'div.widget-content' ).innerText
            ;

            doc.getElementById( 'myIframe' ).src = myNewPage;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you Mac.

Comment: Absolutely. Glad it helped you. 